# Synology Router Port Forwarding

Tags: synology

I need to enable my Synology NAS Workstation to forward its in-built application of My SQL Database, which is 3306.

For some reason this is not showing up in the Router Configuration.

Please see the photos[image: Synology Workstation][image: from forum]

By the way, the second photo with the "forum" look to it is what I used to be able to see (I just randomly picked this photo out of any forum, here is the link: https://forum.synology.com/enu/viewtopic.php?t=52936)

Answer (score 0):

When you open the port in the NAS control panel it shoudl automatically create a rule in your router if its recognized first. If not, just create it manually in your router. If you cannot create a port forwarding try with port-trigger.